# If someone's blocked me, will I be able to search for them on Steam?

Tags: steam

Will I still be able to see the person in the "find people" search, or will they just not show up?

I'd like to know so I can put certain suspicions to rest.

Comment: This sounds like an awfully easy thing to test. Block them, and search. There's your answer.

Comment: He's talking about somebody blocking him, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for advice in getting around a security feature set up by Steam. **If** the user has blocked you, it is not the intentions of Steam to allow you to determine so in any way or form, for the other users privacy. If the other user has blocked you, it simply means they do not wish to communicate or play with you, and it offers no benefit or improvement to know if this is the case, for sure.

Comment: Before others point out the discrepancy, I refer to security feature as a mechanic to protect the user, in this context. A user might block another user for harassing or bullying them, or otherwise making their game-time un-enjoyable. I do not think we should be answering questions on how to tell if one user blocks another, on the basis that the two users could easily know eachother in real life (home, school), and this could lead to more bullying or harassment very easily.

Comment: OP, I do not mean to imply any of this applys to your situation. But we have to look at a question in terms of the community implications, not the intentions of the individual.

Comment: @Timelord64 I disagree. If it is possible to search them, view them, and determine they are blocked because they cannot add/message them then this is **not** asking for advice to get around a security feature. If Valve allows this to happen it is by design. If he was looking to contact him and Valve prevents this through Steam and he can't, still no security measure broken. As far as contact avenues outside of Steam. That is none of Valve's scope, concern, nor business. And the OP is giving no evidence of this intention as well.

Comment: @Timelord64 If you want to call it off topic as it isn't directly gaming related, then I can agree with that.

Comment: Didn't realize this was an old post. It was on my front page. Sorry for reviving this part of the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

If a player has blocked you, and their profile is still Public, then you can still see their profile. However, if you attempt to add them, then you will get an error message saying that you are unable to add them as a friend. Furthermore, attempts to send communication to them will be cut off, even if you attempt to bypass this by finding a similar group the player who has blocked you is also in, and attempt to chat with them this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that you will be able to see their username, but when you click on their profile, you won't be able to access it because you're blocked. If you need to see their profile however, I suggest just visiting steampowered.com on Chrome, and then searching for a user through the website rather than the Steam client.

Edit: Never mind, you have to login to search for a user, and it just takes you to the blocked page. So, no, there are no known loopholes for this.

Comment: No. I am able to view profiles of people who have me blocked, however, I can't add them as friends nor comment on their profiles.